# The Yarn Plug'n'Play manifest forbids importing "XYZ" here because it's not listed as a dependency of this package

Tags: yarnpkg, vite

Yarn 3.5 (stable) using ViteJS - I keep getting this same error for various third party packages. I'm lost on how to properly solve this. The message says I can mark "react" as external, 1) no docs on how to do that, and 2) that would remove it from the bundle which is definitely not a valid solution since my app runs on react.

How do I solve this?

---

`yarn dev` - start start development

yarn created `.yarn` folder, `.pnp.cjs`, `yarn.lock`, and `.pnpn.loader.mjs` files in the root of my repo that it maintains. I don't really have any control over how those things are generated/maintained.

**package.json:**

```
  ...
  "packageManager": "yarn@3.5.0",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "vite --config vite.config.ts",
    "build": "tsc && vite build",
    "preview": "vite preview --config vite.config.ts"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/client": "^3.7.10",
    "chroma-js": "^2.4.2",
    "graphql": "^16.6.0",
    "graphql-ws": "^5.12.0",
    "howler": "^2.2.3",
    "linq": "^4.0.1",
    "lodash.clonedeep": "^4.5.0",
    "luxon": "^3.3.0",
    "primeflex": "^3.3.0",
    "primeicons": "^6.0.1",
    "primereact": "^9.2.1",
    "quill": "^1.3.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.9.0",
    "react-use": "^17.4.0",
    "recoil": "^0.7.7",
    "recoil-sync": "^0.2.0",
    "uuid": "^9.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/chroma-js": "^2",
    "@types/howler": "^2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.5.0",
    "@types/linq": "^2.2.33",
    "@types/lodash.clonedeep": "^4",
    "@types/luxon": "^3.2.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "@types/quill": "^2.0.10",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.28",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.11",
    "@types/uuid": "^9.0.1",
    "@vitejs/plugin-react-swc": "^3.0.0",
    "@yarnpkg/sdks": "^3.0.0-rc.40",
    "autoprefixer": "^10.4.14",
    "concurrently": "^7.6.0",
    "cross-env": "^7.0.3",
    "graphql-config": "^4.5.0",
    "graphql-tag": "^2.12.6",
    "jest": "^29.5.0",
    "postcss": "^8.4.21",
    "prettier": "2.8.6",
    "sass": "^1.60.0",
    "typescript": "^5.0.2",
    "vite": "^4.2.0"
  }
```

**.yarnrc.yml:**

```
nodeLinker: pnp

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.5.0.cjs
```

**`yarn dev` output:**

```
Error: Build failed with 1 error:
../../../.yarn/__virtual__/recoil-sync-virtual-1d8ed1cd8b/0/cache/recoil-sync-npm-0.2.0-8a627829eb-a0bd98acbc.zip/node_modules/recoil-sync/es/index.js:2:18: ERROR: Could not resolve "react"
    at failureErrorWithLog (F:\git\aperture\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.17.13-538abc913d\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1636:15)
    at F:\git\aperture\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.17.13-538abc913d\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1048:25
    at runOnEndCallbacks (F:\git\aperture\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.17.13-538abc913d\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1471:45)
    at buildResponseToResult (F:\git\aperture\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.17.13-538abc913d\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1046:7)
    at F:\git\aperture\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.17.13-538abc913d\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1058:9
    at new Promise (<anonymous>)
    at requestCallbacks.on-end (F:\git\aperture\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.17.13-538abc913d\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1057:54)
    at handleRequest (F:\git\aperture\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.17.13-538abc913d\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:723:19)
    at handleIncomingPacket (F:\git\aperture\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.17.13-538abc913d\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:745:7)
    at Socket.readFromStdout (F:\git\aperture\.yarn\unplugged\esbuild-npm-0.17.13-538abc913d\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:673:7) {
  errors: [
    {
      detail: undefined,
      id: '',
      location: {
        column: 18,
        file: '../../../.yarn/__virtual__/recoil-sync-virtual-1d8ed1cd8b/0/cache/recoil-sync-npm-0.2.0-8a627829eb-a0bd98acbc.zip/node_modules/recoil-sync/es/index.js',
        length: 7,
        line: 2,
        lineText: "import react from 'react';",
        namespace: '',
        suggestion: ''
      },
      notes: [
        {
          location: {
            column: 33,
            file: '../../../.pnp.cjs',
            length: 504,
            line: 10028,
            lineText: '          "packageDependencies": [\\',
            namespace: '',
            suggestion: ''
          },
          text: `The Yarn Plug'n'Play manifest forbids importing "react" here because it's not listed as a dependency of this package:`
        },
        {
          location: null,
          text: 'You can mark the path "react" as external to exclude it from the bundle, which will remove this error.'
        }
      ],
      pluginName: '',
      text: 'Could not resolve "react"'
    }
  ],
  warnings: []
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found an answer. Unclear if this is the correct approach.

1. Change the `pnpMode` in the `.yarnrc.yml` file to `loose`
2. Re-run `yarn install`
3. `yarn dev` should now run successfully without complaining.

---

`.yarnrc.yml:`

```
nodeLinker: pnp
pnpMode: "loose"

plugins:
  - path: .yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript.cjs
    spec: "@yarnpkg/plugin-typescript"

yarnPath: .yarn/releases/yarn-3.5.0.cjs
```

Comment: It doesnt work for me :(

Answer (score 1):

This error comes from the [esbuild resolver](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/blob/main/internal/resolver/resolver.go#L2340), not Yarn. I ran into this where the first step didn't quite work, even after downgrading to Yarn V1.

First, `yarn -v` to see what version you are on then:

## Yarn 2/3+

```
rm -rf node_modules .yarn .pnp.* yarn.lock
```

If you want to keep using pnp nodeLinker, Update `.yarnrc.yml` to include or [change to loose](https://yarnpkg.com/features/pnp#pnp-loose-mode):

```
nodeLinker: pnp
pnpMode: "loose"
```

Otherwise, if you'd rather go for the classic node_modules approach and forgo the pnp benefits, consider changing the [nodeLinker](https://yarnpkg.com/configuration/yarnrc#nodeLinker) to `node_modules`:

```
nodeLinker: node_modules
```

Then reinstall with `yarn install` and attempt to build again.

## Yarn 1 or if the above does not work

If you are still running into this error, look in each of your upstream directories for .pnp.cjs files that may be picked up by Esbuild automatically.

This was my case where my app directory `~/projects/myApp` was clear of yarn files, but `~/projects/.pnp.cjs` is present in the directory above probably generated when I ran yarn accidentally in the wrong dir.

Head back to your project directory and try to build again.